# Combo box in ext js

Tags: extjs

How to render the selected value of combo box in grid of ExtJs?

```
{
    header: 'value', 
    width: 150,
    dataIndex: 'roleType', 
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store: 'RoleStore',
        valueField: 'roleId',
        displayField: 'roleType',
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ExtJS5+, you can use the [widget column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/components/widgets_widgets_columns.html).

```
{
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    header: 'value', 
    width: 150,
    dataIndex: 'roleType', 
    widget: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store: 'RoleStore',
        valueField: 'roleId',
        displayField: 'roleType',
    }
}
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17tv

Comment: I am using ExtJs 4. And the combo box is not rendering the selected value.